# webrtc xcode build for Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, webrtc, chromium

Does anyone know if there is a way to obtain a build for Mac OS X (*not iOS*) for use in an Xcode project? the only examples I've found have been for obtaining iOS based Xcode workspaces, ex:

```
export GYP_GENERATOR_FLAGS="xcode_project_version=3.2 xcode_ninja_target_pattern=All_iOS xcode_ninja_executable_target_pattern=AppRTCDemo|libjingle_peerconnection_unittest|libjingle_peerconnection_objc_test output_dir=out_ios"

export GYP_GENERATORS="ninja,xcode-ninja"
```

Is there any flag that will get me something for use in Mac OS X? I'm just trying to build an app using `webrtc` for Mac OS X.

Comment: Webrtc is now using GN instead of GYP. Have you tried GN to compile WebRtc for macOS?

Answer (score 1):

Google has an example app in their webrtc repo, although I don't think it's built using Xcode.

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc
```

In that repo, you can find it in: `webrtc/examples/objc/AppRTCDemo/`

See the `README` in `webrtc/talk/app/webrtc/objc/README` for build instructions.

---

Another option would be to build a native app using a Node.js/Chromium runtime like [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) or [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron).